# Delete function in hashTable about the object select

Tags: java

In delete function, how to compare the value in hashTable and the value you input, my code was stuck there:

```
//delete router
public void delRouter(String routerNum){

    Iterator it = ht.keySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()){

        String key = it.next().toString();

        //take Router object out
        Router router = (Router)ht.get(key);

        if(router.getRouterNum().equals(routerNum)){

            // delete object
            ht.remove(routerNum);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is ht.remove(); Please give me a hand. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are using `ht.remove(routerNum);` to remove the router from the map suggests that you are using the routers' numbers as keys to the map. In this case, there is no need to iterate all the keys in the map at all! Just call [`ht.remove(routerNum);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) and that's it:

```
public void delRouter(String routerNum){
    ht.remove(routerNum);
}
```

Or, in case you want/have to check that the router in the map really has that number, do this:

```
public void delRouter(String routerNum){
    Router router = (Router) ht.get(key);
    if (router.getRouterNum().equals(routerNum)){
        ht.remove(routerNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing value to `ht.remove(routerNum)` (by passing value, which would work if you pass key) use `ht.remove(key)`

I would advice you to use iterator's [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29) method as `it.remove()`

Comment: yeah, That what I was intend to do, but code stuck there.